# Specific Sikuli project not creating libs folder with mac dylib files

Tags: java, .net, macos, rest, sikuli

I'm using a .NET wrapper for Sikuli called Sikuli4Net (created by tiennen07), this wrapper depends on another project, called Sikulirestapi that are implemented in Java and exposes through REST some core functionalities of Sikuli. The Sikulirestapi has a dependency to a specific sikulixapi.jar that has more dependencies than oficial sikulixapi.jar (generated by oficial Sikuli code from RaiMan), as a result it's bigger.
I separated the project of Sikulirestapi from Sikuli4Net to work like selenium-server standalone, so I can start the Sikulirestapi server through terminal and send parameter to another host remotely.

The problem is when I'm going to start the Sikulirestapi on a Mac, because this specific sikulixapi.jar doesn't have any lib for Mac inside it, only for Windows. When I send commands from a PC to a Mac It's causing the following exception:

```
Instantiated new Screen object...
[error] ResourceLoader: checkLibsDir: Not a valid libs dir for SikuliX (x86_64): /Users/henrique.eguchi/Documents/automacao/SikuliServer/libs
[error] ResourceLoader: checkLibsDir: Not a valid libs dir for SikuliX (x86_64): /Users/henrique.eguchi/Documents/automacao/SikuliServer/libs
[error] ResourceLoader: loadLib: Fatal Error 109: not found: /Users/henrique.eguchi/Documents/automacao/SikuliServer/libs/libVisionProxy.dylib
[error] RunSetup: Problem with SikuliX libs folder - see error log
[error] Terminating SikuliX after a fatal error(109)! Sorry, but it makes no sense to continue!
If you do not have any idea about the error cause or solution, run again
with a Debug level of 3. You might paste the output to the Q&A board.
```

When I go to the current folder of the Sikulirestapi.jar I find a libs folder but nothing inside it, according to above error, this project is not creating the properly dylib files. When I test on a PC, the folder is created correctly with all needed .dll's.

I did not find this specific sikulixapi code, so how can I include the Mac dependencies and make this project create the right files to work properly on this platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I performed the merge between the package that contains the needed dylib from SikuliX project and the sikulirestapi.jar and the problem was solved.